# How to decode \x20\x20background in Swift?

Tags: html, swift

I want to be able to decode a string with the \x20, \x3c format, that I am getting from an HTML, in Swift. I've tried it in python and was able to do it with this code

```py
soupData = dom
encodedSoupData = soupData.encode('utf8')
soupData = encodedSoupData.decode('unicode_escape')
```

where `dom` is `\x20\x20background\x2Dsize\x3A\x20Contain`

The code above returns

```html
  background-size: Contain
```

What I've done in Swift now is this:

- Convert this string into `Data` with the utf8 encoder.
- Try to decode the data back into `String` with the unicode decoder.

Nothing has worked for me till now. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you control the source of this data? As far as I recall, this is a non-standard encoding scheme. It would be better to just have a proper Unicode string from the get-go

Comment: I do not, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation I was finally able to solve this question.

First, we add an extension to `String` to decode Unicode characters:

```swift
extension String {
    var decodingUnicodeCharacters: String { applyingTransform(.init("Hex-Any"), reverse: false) ?? "" }
}
```

Then, we create a regex expression with 2 capture groups-

- The first group is the escaping x character
- The second group is the 2 alphanumeric characters after \x. (In my example, the letters are in uppercase.

```swift
let pattern = #"(\\x)?([0-9A-F]{2})"#
guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .anchorsMatchLines) else { return }
```

We then find the length of the matching string and then use the `stringByReplacingMatches` on `NSRegularExpression` to replace the matches in the range with a template.

The template is where is gets interesting. After a lot of research, I've found out that converting the \xxx string to \u00XX is the only pattern that helps in decoding the string.

```swift
let testString: String = #"\x20\x20background\x2Dsize\x3A\x20Contain"#
let stringRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: testString.utf16.count)
let result = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: testString, range: stringRange, withTemplate: #"\\\u00$2"#)
```

Now, just apply `decodingUnicodeCharacters` on the `result` string.

```swift
print(result.decodingUnicodeCharacters) //Outputs: "  background-size: Contain"
```